# How to use `useFormStatus` and `useFormState` with Formik

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hooks, formik

I am currently working on a new app and attempting to use **Formik** to implement the **next actions**. While I was able to successfully retrieve the data from the actions, I encountered issues with the **useFormStatus** function, as it kept returning **false** values. Strangely, when I removed Formik and used a simple form instead, everything worked perfectly.

I initially attempted to use setSubmitting from Formik, but this resulted in my actions not receiving the formData. Has anyone else experienced this issue before? If needed, I can provide more information and context about the problem.

I'm not sure how to handle the TypeScript for the actions.

TIA.

My package file:

```
"react": "18.2.0",
"next": "^14.0.4",
"typescript": "^5.3.3",
"formik": "2.4.5",
```

My actions file:

```
'use server'
export const action = async(currentState:any, formData:any) => {
  
  if(formData){
    const data = await fetchAPI( formData );
    return data;
  }

  return null;
}
```

My client file:

```
"use client";

import { useFormState, useFormStatus } from "react-dom";

import { FieldControl } from "@/FieldControl";
import FieldWrapper from "@/FieldWrapper";
import FormButton from "@/FormButton";

import { Formik, Form } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { action } from "@/src/actions"


export const SubmitButton = () => {
  const { pending } = useFormStatus();

  console.log(pending); // Always false

  return (
    <FormButton
      title={pending ? "Searching..." : "Search"}
      disabled={pending}
    />
  )
}

const LaunchPage = (props: any) => {
  
  const {
    initialValuesPageData,
  } = props;  

  const initialValues = {
    field1: "",
    field2: "",
    field3: "",
  };
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    field1: Yup.string(),
    field2: Yup.string(),
    field3: Yup.string(),
  });

  const [data, formAction] = useFormState(action, initialValuesPageData);

  return (
    <>
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        validateOnBlur={true}
        onSubmit={formAction}
        onReset={formAction}
      >
        {({ values, handleBlur }) => (
          <Form>
            <FieldControl
              control="text"
              label="Field1"
              name="field1"
              onBlur={handleBlur}
            />
            <FieldControl
              control="text"
              label="Field2"
              name="field2"
              onBlur={handleBlur}
            />
            <FieldControl
              control="text"
              label="Field3"
              name="field3"
              onBlur={handleBlur}
            />
            <SubmitButton />
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
        
      // Data
      {data && (
        <Table data={data} />
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default LaunchPage;
```

I want to check if SubmitButton is pending or not based on form actions and submissions.